# Wrong display of WooCommerce category page title

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I have problem with WooCommerce category page title display, I have no idea why it happens

It's how my category tree looks like:

Smartphone - Main Category
-Cover - Subcategory 
--Apple - Subcategory 
--Samsung - Subcategory 
---Product 1 -Subcategory 
----Product 2
----Product 3 etc.

And its how it is displayed:

When I click 'Smartphone' - title is 'Apple' 
Then when I click 'cover' - title is still 'Apple'
Then when I continue with Apple products title is not changed even when I click lets say subcategory 'Iphone 6' - displayed title is still 'Apple'.

But then interesting part - When I click 'Samsung' after go into 'cover' title change on 'cover' and stick with it after navigate to Samsung items

And problem is only with this a/h1 tag on the top - url and breadcrumbs works good